# Blogger from http to https (SSL problems)

Tags: http, ssl, https, blogger, archive

The problem is that after receiving the SSL certificate, and switch my site from http to https some functions of my site (on my own domain) on the blogger platform, stopped working.

How can I fix the code to make them work again?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadTheArchive(TotalFeed) 
{
    var PostTitles = new Array();
    var PostURLs = new Array();
    var PostYears = new Array();
    var PostMonths = new Array();
    var PostDays = new Array();

    if("entry" in TotalFeed.feed) 
    {
        var PostEntries=TotalFeed.feed.entry.length;
        for(var PostNum=0; PostNum<PostEntries ; PostNum++) 
        {
            var ThisPost = TotalFeed.feed.entry[PostNum];
            PostTitles.push(ThisPost.title.$t);
            PostYears.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(0,4));
            PostMonths.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(5,7));
            PostDays.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(8,10));
            var ThisPostURL;
            for(var LinkNum=0; LinkNum < ThisPost.link.length; LinkNum++) 
            {
                if(ThisPost.link[LinkNum].rel == "alternate") 
                {
                    ThisPostURL = ThisPost.link[LinkNum].href;
                    break
                }
            }
            PostURLs.push(ThisPostURL);
        }
    }
    DisplaytheTOC(PostTitles,PostURLs,PostYears,PostMonths,PostDays);
}

function DisplaytheTOC(PostTitles,PostURLs,PostYears,PostMonths,PostDays)
{
    var MonthNames=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
    var NumberOfEntries=PostTitles.length;
    var currentMonth = "";
    var currentYear = "";

    for(var EntryNum = 0; EntryNum < NumberOfEntries; EntryNum++)
    {
        NameOfMonth = MonthNames[parseInt(PostMonths[EntryNum],10)-1]

        if (currentMonth != NameOfMonth || currentYear != PostYears[EntryNum]) 
        {
            currentMonth = NameOfMonth;
            currentYear = PostYears[EntryNum];

            document.write("<div class='dateStyle'><br />" + currentMonth+" "+currentYear+" </div>");
        }

        document.write('<a href ="'+PostURLs[EntryNum]+'"><div class=dayStyle>'+parseInt(PostDays[EntryNum],10)+":&nbsp;&nbsp;</div> "+PostTitles[EntryNum]+"</a><br />");
    }
}
</script>

<script src="https://mywebsite.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=500&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=LoadTheArchive" />
</script>
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=151&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"></script>
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=301&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"></script>
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=451&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"></script>
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=601&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"></script>
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=851&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"></script>
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=1001&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"></script>

<!--CUSTOMIZATION-->
<style type="text/css">
.dateStyle {
     color:#000;
     font-size: 30px;
     font-family: Fjalla One;
     margin: 0;
}

.dayStyle {
     color:#000;
     font-family: Droid Sans;
     display: inline-block;
}

</style>
```

And now the form says that it looks like my post is mostly code, a I need to add some more details, but I don't know what to add more, because all what I needed, I was asked above.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are receiving? Is any file still loaded over plain http? It is possible the browser refuses to load some files due to mixing http and https.

Comment: I haven't received any error, cuz it' blogger platform. I just don't see the result of this code.

Comment: You can also check developer tools (F12) in most browsers, check in "Console" and "Network" for any errors.

Comment: Give us a link to your site

Comment: @ext, Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-KMHDS79 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
default Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
default Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
default Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
default Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
default Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
default Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: default Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
almanac.html:1842 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.ias is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (domain.html:1842)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: @coffee-bean, sorry I can't :(

Comment: Bassam was right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about changing script tags to the following

```
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?max-results=500&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=151&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=301&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=451&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=601&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=851&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=1001&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
```

Comment: @Coffeebean, It is valid with XML. By default, blogger editor closes any empty tags that way and when retrieving data, blogger xml parser converts xml code to a valid html to displaying on the browsers.