# Blogger javascript not working http to https

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, blogger, archive

Hello I've just changed the domain from tecnoriales.win to tecnoriales.com and started using SSL (HTTPS).

I have a script that creates an archive of all my post but is not working anymore. I know very little about coding, so I have no clue.

Heres the page where the code should load: https://www.tecnoriales.com/p/sitemap.html

Already took a look to a VERY similar question: [Blogger from http to https (SSL problems)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47366784/blogger-from-http-to-https-ssl-problems) Tried what they said (or so i think) but I was not able to fix the problem.

````
<div style="text-align: justify;">
<span style="font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot; , sans-serif;">A 
continuación tienes la lista de todas las entradas del blog. Recuerda 
que también puedes utilizar la opción Buscar este blog que se encuentra 
en la esquina superior izquierda para indagar.</span><br />
<span style="font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot; , sans-serif;">
</span></div>
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadTheArchive(TotalFeed) 
{
    var PostTitles = new Array();
    var PostURLs = new Array();
    var PostYears = new Array();
    var PostMonths = new Array();
    var PostDays = new Array();
    if("entry" in TotalFeed.feed) 
    {
 var PostEntries=TotalFeed.feed.entry.length;
 for(var PostNum=0; PostNum<postentries ; PostNum++) 
 {
     var ThisPost = TotalFeed.feed.entry[PostNum];
     PostTitles.push(ThisPost.title.$t);
     PostYears.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(0,4));
     PostMonths.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(5,7));
     PostDays.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(8,10));
     var ThisPostURL;
     for(var LinkNum=0; LinkNum < ThisPost.link.length; LinkNum++) 
     {
  if(ThisPost.link[LinkNum].rel == "alternate") 
  {
      ThisPostURL = ThisPost.link[LinkNum].href;
      break
  }
     }
     PostURLs.push(ThisPostURL);
 }
    }
    DisplaytheTOC(PostTitles,PostURLs,PostYears,PostMonths,PostDays);
}

function DisplaytheTOC(PostTitles,PostURLs,PostYears,PostMonths,PostDays)
{
    var MonthNames=["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"];
    var NumberOfEntries=PostTitles.length;

    var currentMonth = "";
    var currentYear = "";

    for(var EntryNum = 0; EntryNum < NumberOfEntries; EntryNum++)
    {
 NameOfMonth = MonthNames[parseInt(PostMonths[EntryNum],10)-1]

 if (currentMonth != NameOfMonth || currentYear != PostYears[EntryNum]) {
  currentMonth = NameOfMonth;
  currentYear = PostYears[EntryNum];

  document.write("<div class='dateStyle'><br />" + currentMonth+" "+currentYear+" </div>
");
 }

  document.write('<a href ="'+PostURLs[EntryNum]+'"><div class=dayStyle>
'+parseInt(PostDays[EntryNum],10)+":&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
"+PostTitles[EntryNum]+"</a><br />");
    }
}
</script>

<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=500&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=LoadTheArchive">
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=151&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=301&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=451&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=601&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=851&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=1001&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive"/>

<!--CUSTOMIZATION-->
<style type="text/css">
.dateStyle {
     color:#000;
     font-weight:bold;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
     margin: 0;
}

.dayStyle {
     color:#000;
     font-weight:bold;
     font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
     display: inline-block;
}

</style></script>```

It should load the full list of all the blog post I've made categorized by month and year but it loads nothing.
````

Comment: Your script tags like `<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=X&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive">` don't have closing tags. Try to close them.

Comment: Try disabling CloudFlare's Rocket Loader feature and see if that makes any difference

Comment: @PrayagVerma Disabled it but makes no difference.

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev I added </script> at the end of all 7 tags, nothing changed still not loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that your callback function was not defined.

So, define your functions as [function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/2777988). This way the function definition exists for the callback to work.

`var LoadTheArchive = function (TotalFeed)`

`var DisplaytheTOC = function (`

Run the snippet below to see it work. Loading links takes a while. So, please wait patiently.

```html
<div style="text-align: justify;">
  <span style="font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot; , sans-serif;">A 
continuación tienes la lista de todas las entradas del blog. Recuerda 
que también puedes utilizar la opción Buscar este blog que se encuentra 
en la esquina superior izquierda para indagar.</span><br />
  <span style="font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot; , sans-serif;">
</span></div>
<br />

<script>
  var LoadTheArchive = function(TotalFeed) {
    var PostTitles = new Array();
    var PostURLs = new Array();
    var PostYears = new Array();
    var PostMonths = new Array();
    var PostDays = new Array();
    if ("entry" in TotalFeed.feed) {
      var PostEntries = TotalFeed.feed.entry.length;
      for (var PostNum = 0; PostNum < PostEntries; PostNum++) {
        var ThisPost = TotalFeed.feed.entry[PostNum];
        PostTitles.push(ThisPost.title.$t);
        PostYears.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(0, 4));
        PostMonths.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(5, 7));
        PostDays.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(8, 10));
        var ThisPostURL;
        for (var LinkNum = 0; LinkNum < ThisPost.link.length; LinkNum++) {
          if (ThisPost.link[LinkNum].rel == "alternate") {
            ThisPostURL = ThisPost.link[LinkNum].href;
            break
          }
        }
        PostURLs.push(ThisPostURL);
      }
    }
    DisplaytheTOC(PostTitles, PostURLs, PostYears, PostMonths, PostDays);
  }

  var DisplaytheTOC = function(PostTitles, PostURLs, PostYears, PostMonths, PostDays) {
    var MonthNames = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
    var NumberOfEntries = PostTitles.length;

    var currentMonth = "";
    var currentYear = "";

    for (var EntryNum = 0; EntryNum < NumberOfEntries; EntryNum++) {
      NameOfMonth = MonthNames[parseInt(PostMonths[EntryNum], 10) - 1]

      if (currentMonth != NameOfMonth || currentYear != PostYears[EntryNum]) {
        currentMonth = NameOfMonth;
        currentYear = PostYears[EntryNum];

        document.write("<div class='dateStyle'><br />" + currentMonth + " " + currentYear + " </div>");
      }

      document.write('<a href ="' + PostURLs[EntryNum] + '"><div class=dayStyle>' + parseInt(PostDays[EntryNum], 10) + ":&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>" + PostTitles[EntryNum] + "</a><br />");
    }
  }
</script>

<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=500&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=LoadTheArchive" />
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=151&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive" />
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=301&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive" />
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=451&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive" />
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=601&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive" />
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=851&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive" />
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=150&start-index=1001&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadTheArchive" />

<!--CUSTOMIZATION-->
<style type="text/css">
  .dateStyle {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .dayStyle {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks now it loads, howver text has no format, the CSS part is not working.

Comment: I had separated the CSS to the CSS section for clarity. I just put the CSS <style> tag back to the HTML as you initially had.

Comment: Yeah i realized that, so that wasnt the problem, is just not applying the style part at the end. Now your edited script does not load the style either when i click on run snippet, however your first one, where you had things separated it did, i worked as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Linebreaks within the JavaScript code leads to Syntax errors. Also `PostEntries` variable was referenced as `postentries`. Change the Javascript as follows -

```html
<script>
function LoadTheArchive(TotalFeed) 
{
    var PostTitles = new Array();
    var PostURLs = new Array();
    var PostYears = new Array();
    var PostMonths = new Array();
    var PostDays = new Array();
    if("entry" in TotalFeed.feed) 
    {
 var PostEntries=TotalFeed.feed.entry.length;
 for(var PostNum=0; PostNum<PostEntries ; PostNum++) 
 {
     var ThisPost = TotalFeed.feed.entry[PostNum];
     PostTitles.push(ThisPost.title.$t);
     PostYears.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(0,4));
     PostMonths.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(5,7));
     PostDays.push(ThisPost.published.$t.substring(8,10));
     var ThisPostURL;
     for(var LinkNum=0; LinkNum < ThisPost.link.length; LinkNum++) 
     {
  if(ThisPost.link[LinkNum].rel == "alternate") 
  {
      ThisPostURL = ThisPost.link[LinkNum].href;
      break
  }
     }
     PostURLs.push(ThisPostURL);
 }
    }
    DisplaytheTOC(PostTitles,PostURLs,PostYears,PostMonths,PostDays);
}

function DisplaytheTOC(PostTitles,PostURLs,PostYears,PostMonths,PostDays)
{
    var MonthNames=["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"];
    var NumberOfEntries=PostTitles.length;

    var currentMonth = "";
    var currentYear = "";

    for(var EntryNum = 0; EntryNum < NumberOfEntries; EntryNum++)
    {
 NameOfMonth = MonthNames[parseInt(PostMonths[EntryNum],10)-1]

 if (currentMonth != NameOfMonth || currentYear != PostYears[EntryNum]) {
  currentMonth = NameOfMonth;
  currentYear = PostYears[EntryNum];

  document.write("<div class='dateStyle'><br />" + currentMonth+" "+currentYear+" </div>");
 }

  document.write('<a href ="'+PostURLs[EntryNum]+'"><div class=dayStyle>'+parseInt(PostDays[EntryNum],10)+":&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>"+PostTitles[EntryNum]+"</a><br />");
    }
}
</script>
<script src="https://tecnoriales.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=500&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=LoadTheArchive" />
```

You will notice that last 2 `document.write` statements have the linebreaks removed